# I can't parse this html code using C# agility pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I've been trying to parse this code for a very long time:

```html
<html>
<body class="detailpage">
    <div id="innerLayout">
        <section id="body-container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content" id="offer_active">
                    <div class="clr offerbody">
                        <div class="offercontent fleft rel ">
                            <div class="offercontentinner">
                                <script>
                                    texto = {"name":"John"};
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I prefer using AgilityPack, and I want to get `"name" : "John"` as a result, but I have not been successful.

This is my attempt:

```cs
string stringThatKeepsYourHtml = @"<!DOCTYPE html> <head> <title>Title</title> </head> <body> <div id=""myId"" class=""myClass""> <div class=""myClass"">hello</div> </div> </body> </html>"; 
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(stringThatKeepsYourHtml); 
string whatUrLookingFor = doc.DocumentNode.
    SelectNodes("//div").
    First().
    SelectNodes("//div").
    First().
    InnerText; 
Console.WriteLine(whatUrLookingFor); 
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Show your best version of the code and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: @ADyson ```
            string stringThatKeepsYourHtml = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=""myId"" class=""myClass"">
    < div class=""myClass"">hello</div>
  </div>
</body>";
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(stringThatKeepsYourHtml);
            string whatUrLookingFor = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div").First().SelectNodes("//div").First().InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(whatUrLookingFor);
            Console.ReadLine();```

Comment: Hi. As you can see, it's quite hard to read the code when it's placed in the comments like this. Stackoverflow isn't like a standard discussion forum (see the [tour] for more info). Your question has an "edit" button under it, which you can use to improve the main question, then the information is visible, all in one place, and can be formatted properly. To allow us to consider your code fully, please edit your question and place it there. [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) may be useful to read as well. Thankyou.

Comment: That second `//div` starts from the root again. Start with a dot: `.//div`

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the problem with parsing it is.. This worked fine:

```
        var html = @"
<html>
<body class=""detailpage"">
    <div id=""innerLayout"">
        <section id=""body-container"">
            <div class=""wrapper"">
                <div class=""content"" id=""offer_active"">
                    <div class=""clr offerbody"">
                        <div class=""offercontent fleft rel "">
                            <div class=""offercontentinner"">
                                <script>
                                    texto = {""name"":""John""};
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        string scr = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script").InnerText;
        
        Console.WriteLine(scr);
```

`scr` contains the full script `texto = {"name":"John"}` - you can remove the `texto =` and then json parse the remainder, or just take everything between `{` and `}` using some substring, for example:

```
var openBra = scr.IndexOf('{');
var closeBra = scr.LastIndexOf('}');
var between = scr[openBra+1..closeBra]; //c# version 8 ranges feature, use Substring if you're on c# <8
```

I'm not really clear on what you wanted to do with it

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uinjl6